# How to charge 4 NiMh AA batteries with solar cell

Tags: batteries, solar-cell

I have a nice 6V solar panel and I was thinking to use it to recharge a 4xAA NiMh battery pack (nominal voltage 4.8).

Is it enough to put a series diode (0.7v) to drop the voltage, or do I have to use a current limiter?

Comment: Look up charge balancing with respect to charging batteries.  The short answer may be it is best to charge cells individually rather what you are inferring to do.  That is, I think you are thinking of charging them in series.

Comment: yes, in series, as I need to power a circuit downstream.

Comment: Will the solar panel always produce exactly 6v? If it does not how do you change the dropping voltage?

Comment: @FabioMarzocca, Charging a 4s1p pack while still using it is not trivial.  A special chip called a [PMIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_management_integrated_circuit) is used in cell phones and other portable devices.  There is a whole family of chips by ti.com devoted to this.  If you want  to charge the same 4s1p pack over and over, while using the pack at the same time, this will turn into a rather complex project.

Comment: @SolarMike, the solar panel connot always produce 6v. But the batteries output is the input of a stepup DC/DC converter (input: 3-9v, output 11v).

Comment: What stepup DC/DC converter? Not mentioned in your question... If there is one, then add it to your question so we know what you are talking about.

Comment: @SolarMike, I didn't added it as it is not related to the question. I have an Arduino/ESP8266 circuit to be powered from batteries+MT3608 stepup converted.   Here: https://www.olimex.com/Products/Breadboarding/BB-PWR-3608/resources/MT3608.pdf

Comment: @FabioMarzocca any information you can provide about your intended system is better to provide in the question.  To some degree the step up converter is not directly relevant, however you would be surprised at the instinctive level of effort many people around here put in.  At the least they might check the properties of the stepup converter (Input current and efficiency curves in particular) to ensure any system recommended suits the rest of the system.

Comment: If you want to use the NiMh batteries in series, this is not impossible or forbidden, but it would be best if you grouped a set of brand new matched batteries for the purpose, and you should use a board specifically designed to charge and discharge the batteries.  Given these two things, it should be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solar panel are current source rather than a voltage source.

This means, if you connect your solar panel to your battery, the solar panel will be forced to operate at whatever voltage your batteries are at.

To be more efficient, you should use a MPPT controller, but if you don't need a whole bunch of power you can just directly connect them.

What is more complex is on the battery side, as it needs some precise charging control, especially NiMh. If you use these batteries, you will need some complex circuitry.

However, if you can swap the batteries for more tolerant ones. If space and weight is not an issue, a Lead Acid battery would be the easiest to charge, otherwise a Li-Ion battery would also work.

Here is a very simple schematic that you can hack together to charge lead acid or li-ion batteries by having a voltage cut-off, we consider the panel is small and that the current doesn't need to be limited.

You can limit the panel current output by shadowing it using some tape if needed.

It would be better to use opamp and correct circuitry but I consider given your application that you need something simple to build.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fv14o2.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Basically when the voltage on the battery reach a certain level, Q4 will conduct and short the panel to the ground, stopping charging the battery. You can adjust the desired voltage with R2. The Schtocky diode is there to prevent discharing the battery during night. Perhaos R2 can be significantly increased to reduce leakage current.